# Обрезается текст при повороте

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

когда я поворачиваю текст внутри бокса у него меняется позиция.

Вот мой код:

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .fillMaxHeight(0.2f)
        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(5.dp))
        .shadow(5.dp)
        .background(Color(0xFFD88EDD))
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .fillMaxWidth(0.12f)
            .background(Color(0xFFC27FC6)),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "27 DECC",
            color = Color.White,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            fontFamily = fontFamily,
            fontSize = 13.sp,
            modifier = Modifier
                .rotate(-90f)
                .background(Color.Red),
        )
    }
}
```

Я пробовал использовать свойство softWrap в значении false, тогда ситуация меняется, но сам текст обрезается. Здесь я не использую softWrap: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7w87M.png, здесь использую: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYlIj.png. Возможно ответ на мой вопрос уже дан здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70014899/rotated-text-gets-cropped, но в моей ситуации данное решение не сработало. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Непонятно что вы хотите получить